# Android build , Directory.exist = true in editor but not in build

Tags: android, directory, resources, android-build

I'm trying to load a text that i put inside a folder in the "Resources" folder.
I get the path using :

```
var mainPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources");
```

but when i do :

```
if (Directory.Exists(mainPath))....
```

alwais return false on android build, but it works on the editor.

TY for your time, have a nice day :).

Comment: You are with Android device in town and try to reach a file in Resources folder on your PC at home?

Comment: No, i builded the app with a Resources folder inside the assets folder where i put the txt i wanted ti read. Am i doing something wrong ? Sorry i am new to programming @.@ , ty for your time :)

Comment: How does mainPath look like?

Comment: Data/app/com.myapp..../base.apk

Comment: There is no path to a file in assets. You have to use the assets manager.

Comment: Why shouldnt i be able to access the Resources folder the way I did ?

Comment: Because you have yo use the assets manager. Didnt i say that before!